# MediaPlayer not being stopped in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working with a RecyclerView which takes ArrayList of integer value of drawables and mp3 files from raw. The MediaPlayer in the recyclerview adapter is working fine but when the user goes back and opens the activity again, the player is playing in the background and there are new list items of mp3 files, not played. I am attaching the code. Help me out, thanks.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context,sounds.get(position));

    if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        holder.play.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }

    holder.play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                holder.play.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                holder.play.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_puase);
                mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You're creating a MediaPlayer for each Row of the RecycleView....it's crazy. The music continues in background because the current playing MediaPlayer was created from a Context that continue to live/be_referenced even if the Activity is closed. I think you have to complete review the approach........

Comment: @emandt , How can I solve this? I want to stop the music when user presses back or comes back to the activity.

Comment: You need to create only one "MediaPlayer" and save it in the Activity class. Then call "mediaplayer.stop()" and "mediaPlayer.release()" in "Activity.onStop()" event. Obliviously when you press different RecycleView items you have to stop currently MediaPlayer listening before start the new one.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a method from your activity's onStop or onDestroy on your adapter and handle the stopping of the mediaplayer and clearing resources.

In your activity

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mAdapter.clearMediaPlayer(); // calling the method inside your adapter
}
```

in your adapter..

```
public void clearMediaPlayer() {
    if(mp!=null){
          mp.stop();
          mp.release();// this will clear memory
          mp = null;
    }
}
```

I would strongly suggest you to implement your mediaplayer in your activity if you were to play only a single recyclerview item at a time.